Can I get all hyperlinks that contain "@" then open them in new tabs?
I'm trying to open all hyperlinks on a page with link text that includes the "@" symbol.
Here's an example below
[test@gmail.com](https://stackoverflow.com/2342342352) 
[something@gmail.com](https://stackoverflow.com/2342525233423)
[blahblah@gmail.com](https://stackoverflow.com/23943234)

So far, I can collect each of the lines that include an @ symbol with this jQuery selector:
$("a:contains('@')")

This gives me a list of every anchor tag that has @ in the link text, it looks like this:
jQuery.fn.init {0: a, 1:a, 2:a,}

For a cleaner array, I used
$("a:contains('@')").get

Which returns
(3) [a, a, a]

I tried using this for loop to click every a tag in the array but as soon as I click the first one, it stops.
var mapps = $("a:contains('@')").get()

for (var i = 0, len = mapps.length; i < len; i++) {
  mapps[i].click();
}

So to open multiple links in new tabs, I'm going to try using window.open() which I believe requires the URL.
I can extract the URL in the first anchor tag by using this code:
$("a:contains('@')").prop('href');

However, .prop only returns the first URL.
Is there a way for me to return all URLs then feed them into a for loop and open them in new tabs?
I'm trying to figure this out with .each() but it's been very difficult for me. Please let me know if you need more context and forgive my lack of experience.

jquery has an .each method you can use

You can use the each and $(this).prop('href')


$("a:contains('@')").each(function() {
  window.open($(this).prop('href'), '_blank');
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/2342342352">test@gmail.com</a>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/2342525233423">something@gmail.com</a>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/23943234">blahblah@gmail.com</a>




First, you really don't need jQuery for this.
What you want to do is loop over each discovered element, extract the href property and use open() with a target of _blank to open the tabs


// window.open doesn't work in snippets so here's a mock
window.open = (...args) => console.log('window.open', ...args);

[...document.querySelectorAll('a[href]')]
  .filter(({ textContent }) => textContent.includes('@'))
  .forEach(({ href }) => {
    window.open(href, '_blank');
  });
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/2342342352">test@gmail.com</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/2342525233423">something@gmail.com</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/23943234">blahblah@gmail.com</a>
  </li>
</ul>  




I found it to be working when you set target property to _blank so they would open on different windows. I used vanilla JS to select the anchors.
Note: Next snippet won't work in sandbox mode.


var links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a')).filter(link => {
  return link.textContent.indexOf("@") >= 0
});
console.log(links)

links.forEach(link => {
  link.target = "_blank"
  link.click()
})
<p><a target="_blank" href="https://exmaple.com/">link@there</a></p>
<p><a target="_blank" href="https://exmaple2.com/">ano@ther.com</a></p>




THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!!
I've been smacking my head against my keyboard the past two days trying to do this.
This is amazing.

I'd be wary of changing the document by adding / overriding target properties since it would affect the normal / expected operation

Given an array of Urls...
var Urls = [];

Which you can fill in with...
Urls.push('https://someplace.com');

Then to fire them all up use...
let a=document.createElement('a'); 

a.target='_blank';



for(let i=0; i<Urls.length; i++){

 a.href=Urls[i];

 a.click();

}

